# A consistent and simple group of IDE and tools for embedded code and unit test in C++?

Tags: embedded, mocking, eclipse-cdt, cppunit, texas-instruments

I’m starting a new firmware project in **C++** for Texas Instrument **C283xx and C6xxx targets**.
The unit tests **will not run on the target**, but will be compiled with **gcc/gcov** on a PC with windows (and run as well on PC) with simple metrics for tested code coverage.

The whole project will be part of Cruise Control.NET for continuous integrations.

My question is: what are the consistent IDE / framework / tools to work together?

A/ One of the developers says **CodeComposerStudio V3.1** for application and **CodeBlocks + CxxUnit** for the Unit tests.

B/ I’m more attracted with **CodeComposerStudio V4** for application, **Eclipse CDT** (well, as CCS V4) and **CppUnit** for unit test + **MockCpp** for mocks.

**I don’t want the best in class tools for each process**, but a global, consistent and easy solution (or group of tools if you prefer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, google C++ Test Framework and google C++ Mocking Framework might be a better option. It works with eclipse cdt, and the output can be generated in the xml format for CI servers.

Comment: yeah, I find it very usefull and it's compatible with Eclipse CDT.
Thx !

Answer (score 0):

I understand the Unit tests not running on the target.  But you might want test coverage collected in the target anyway.

See [SD C++ Test Coverage](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CppTestCoverage.html) for a tool that operates with minimal footprint in a practical way inside most targets.   You have to customize a provided small data collection procedure for this to work; normally an afternoons' straightforward exercise.

Comment: Thx for the link, but I'm still searching a group of tools !